# How can I install openjdk 8 and sbt on mac and have openjdk 8 (not 13) the default one?

Tags: java, macos, scala, sbt

Installing java 8 and sbt with brew and/or brew cask is clearly possible,
The problem I am hitting is that brew installs java 13 as sbt dependency,

And I do not know a general way to go back to java 8 as default, since there are so many ways potentially to opt between java version some of which i am aware include PATH, JAVA_HOME, ln -s, java_exec selector.

Another problem potentially is that brew install sbt installs brew install java which is 13,
But java 8 I install it via brew cask.

The TL is saying that Java 13 or 14 might be causing some issues e.g. tests fails, should I push for latest versions of OpenJdk, Scala, SBT, etc?

Comment: Just set `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` in your user env

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, SDK Man is an option.
It actually works with **brew** also but there need to be just a few manual steps: here they are:

Installing sbt, java8, jenv & configure the shell

We used brew to install sbt (which in its turn installs java 13), and brew cask to install openjdk java 8, like this:

```
brew install sbt
brew tap AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk
brew cask install adoptjava8
```

We will use jenv to manage the java versions, with the information from https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/31390

Basically the next steps are:

```
brew install jenv
jenv init -
echo 'eval "$(jenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'eval "$(jenv init -)"' >> ~/.zprofile
jenv add <path-to-java8-Home-Dir>
```

**Then restart your terminal** and you should now be able to run `sbt`

Where at time of writing `<path-to-java8-Home-Dir>` is `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home`

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at a utility like [Sdk Man](https://sdkman.io/).

It is multi-platform and allows you to set any desired JDK as a default one.

As well as changing it to another provider/version when it will be required.