# sbt won't install correctly; homebrew changing java versions

Tags: java, scala, sbt, homebrew

I just did a clean install.  jdk 8 (from adoptium.net) and sbt (using homebrew) on a newly imaged macbook.  Somehow homebrew used java 18 anyway, and sbt doesn't work.

I followed the instructions here:  https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Installing-sbt-on-Mac.html

Following the link on that page to adoptium.net, I found the only jdk 8 for mac os.

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_322"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Temurin)(build 1.8.0_322-b06)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Temurin)(build 25.322-b06, mixed mode)
```

Following the instructions on the sbt page, I used homebrew...

```
$ brew install sbt
```

When I check the version, I see a problem...

```
$ sbt about
[info] welcome to sbt 1.6.2 (Homebrew Java 18)
[info] loading project definition from /Users/KHinson1/project
[info] set current project to khinson1 (in build file:/Users/KHinson1/)
[info] This is sbt 1.6.2
[info] The current project is ProjectRef(uri("file:/Users/KHinson1/"), "khinson1") 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.12.15
```

Homebrew installed it using java 18?!  How do I clean this up and use the java 8 that I installed?  I can't find java 18 on my laptop.

I immediately run into problems trying to compile a fat jar with `sbt assembly`...

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The Security Manager is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
  at java.base/java.lang.System.setSecurityManager(System.java:416)
  at sbt.TrapExit$.installManager(TrapExit.scala:52)
  at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:52)
  at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:28)
  at xsbt.boot.Launch$.$anonfun$run$1(Launch.scala:149)
  at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:176)
  at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:149)
  at xsbt.boot.Launch$.$anonfun$apply$1(Launch.scala:44)
  at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:159)
  at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:44)
  at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:21)
  at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:78)
  at xsbt.boot.Boot$.run(Boot.scala:73)
  at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:21)
  at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] [launcher] error during sbt launcher: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The Security Manager is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
```

I know this is a java 17+ problem from questions like this...

[sbt assembly cannot create jar getting java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71832118/sbt-assembly-cannot-create-jar-getting-java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception)

I've used homebrew in the past to install sbt, but I'm honestly new to macs and don't understand how it's using java 18 when I didn't install java 18.

How do I get java 18 completely off my machine (I can't even find it) and get sbt installed with java 8 as intended?

Thanks.

**edit**

I've tried using jenv as outlined here:  [How can I install openjdk 8 and sbt on mac and have openjdk 8 (not 13) the default one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61067260/how-can-i-install-openjdk-8-and-sbt-on-mac-and-have-openjdk-8-not-13-the-defau)

I point it at the openjdk I installed

```
$ which java
/usr/bin/java
```

but when I try

```
$ jenv add /usr/bin/java
/usr/bin/java is not a valid path to java installation
```

(**edit** I've blown everything out now to try SDKMAN, but I wonder if I should have pointed to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin_???` directly?)

I tried using `brew install sbt@0.13` which lists jdk 8 as its dependency, but it just didn't function ("command not found").  I want a newer sbt, but I think specifying something like `sbt.version=1.3.6` in build.properties would force sbt to upgrade later.

I tried "expanding the zip" as suggested on the sbt install page, but same thing ("command not found"), now matter where I expand it to or how I update the path.

**edit 2**

i'm open to trying sdkman, but at this point I've tried installing/uninstalling a few things, and I don't know how to get java off my machine, and I'm worried about messing it all up with too many competing attempts.

Comment: I recommend checking out [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/) and install your jdk/sbt via it. it means you need to remove them from brew first and then reinstall with `sdk`. it allows you to manage different versions of sdks and switch between the versions easily

Comment: I think you can try `brew doctor` first before anything

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The SDKMAN recommendation by @Ivan Stanislavciuc was a great one.  It's really easy how it manages java environments.

Here's my process to back out of my false starts, and get things working.

```
# uninstall everything
brew uninstall sbt
brew uninstall jenv
cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
sudo rm -rf <java installation>

# install sdkman
curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash

# select java version 
# (I chose temurin jdk 8 which is formerly openj9; 
#  can't find hotspot AdoptOpenJdk anymore, is it gone?)
sdk list java
sdk install java 8.0.322-tem
sdk default java 8.0.322-tem

# install sbt
sdk install sbt
```

That easy.

I used to use the hotspot adopt open jdk...  but I didn't see that one available anywhere now.  I see hotspot is still the recommendation on the sbt install page in the SDKMAN instructions (`.hs-adpt` is "hotspot adopt open jdk"?).  But temurin is the openj9 I think, and it matches the adoptium.net link also on the sbt page, so for now I assume that's ok.

Comment: I can confirm this worked for me; I'm using Ventura 13.2.1

Comment: "sbt console" at the end will be appreciated because there are no sbt on computer right after "sdk install sbt" execution - just some "candidate" link in SDKMan.

Comment: I think all I did was `sdk install sbt`, and then I have a `build.sbt` file in whatever directory I launch `sbt console` from.  I have a new laptop I need to setup so I'll run through this process again in the next week or so and I'll add an edit w/ anything I find.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can install specific java versions inside brew. Use `brew cask install java8` (of course you'll need to have cask installed first, `brew install cask`).

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue which you mentioned after I changed my Mac and reinstalled sbt. Now since i did not get the exact solution executing this (sudo sbt -java-home /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home assembly ) to run assembly command.

Comment: I'd try SDKMAN, and the temurin releases are the new names for what was formerly openj9 adoptOpenJdk.  it has cleared up my issues so far.  this tutorial is a reasonable quick start:  https://reflectoring.io/manage-jdks-with-sdkman/

Answer (score -1):

I am using java 11, jenv, just did the `brew install sbt`, there is no problem on my side.

```
$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.11 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 (build 11.0.11+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 (build 11.0.11+9, mixed mode)
```

```
$ brew reinstall sbt
...
==> Reinstalling sbt
==> Pouring sbt--1.6.2.all.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
You can use $SBT_OPTS to pass additional JVM options to sbt.
Project specific options should be placed in .sbtopts in the root of your project.
Global settings should be placed in /opt/homebrew/etc/sbtopts

Homebrew's installation does not include `sbtn`.
==> Summary
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/sbt/1.6.2: 8 files, 3.7MB
```

```
$ sbt about
[info] Updated file /Users/rui/Downloads/sbt-test/project/build.properties: set sbt.version to 1.6.2
[info] welcome to sbt 1.6.2 (AdoptOpenJDK Java 11.0.11)
[info] loading project definition from /Users/rui/Downloads/sbt-test/project
[info] set current project to sbt-test (in build file:/Users/rui/Downloads/sbt-test/)
[info] This is sbt 1.6.2
[info] The current project is ProjectRef(uri("file:/Users/rui/Downloads/sbt-test/"), "sbt-test") 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.12.15
[info] Available Plugins
[info]  - sbt.ScriptedPlugin
[info]  - sbt.plugins.CorePlugin
[info]  - sbt.plugins.Giter8TemplatePlugin
[info]  - sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin
[info]  - sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin
[info]  - sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin
[info]  - sbt.plugins.MiniDependencyTreePlugin
[info]  - sbt.plugins.SbtPlugin
[info]  - sbt.plugins.SemanticdbPlugin
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.12.15
```

I would suggest two things for troubleshooting:

- checkout `PATH` thing
- run `brew doctor`